# AngularJS - Placeholder value change automatically

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<md-input-container class="md-block hide-error-space" flex="25">
<input required name="code" ng-model="code">
</md-input-container>
```

Here is the textbox for the user to input the code.

```
<md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block hide-error-space" flex="50">
    <input name="Hooter" ng-readonly="true" ng-model="hooter"
           placeholder="Please input the code">
</md-input-container>
```

And this is another textbox where I want to let the placeholder shows "Please input the code" when the textbox for code is null and shows "The code is: {{code}}" when the code is input.

Is there any way I can write a condition for the placeholder?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
    Code: <input required name="code" ng-model="code">
    <br>
    Hooter: <input name="Hooter" ng-readonly="!code" ng-model="hooter"
              placeholder="{{!code?'input the code':'the code is '+code}}" />
</body>
```